# Compact subset of a non compact topological space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Define a topological space X that is not compact and define a set A ⊂ X that is compact.  Use the definition of finite open subcovers to show that A is compact.

Ok so I think that a topological space that would not be compact could be the set of integers Z on standard topology. A subset could be [-3,3]. But I am not sure how to so that [-3,3] is compact using the definition of open subcovers.

Comment: Try to show that a discrete space is compact iff it is finite. Then you can take your example (provided you use the notation $[-3,3]$ to mean $[-3,3] \cap \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Use say the reals with the usual topology for $X$. And now let's cheat, use a one point set for $A$, or even the empty set.

Comment: @MattSamuel I've never seen a convention where "compact" implied "nonempty." Is this sometimes assumed?

Comment: @Noah Not as far as I know. I was actually making a joke...I also find it a bit silly to say the empty set isn't connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb{Z}$, the interval $[-3, 3]$ - that is, $\{-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3\}$ - is compact because it is finite, and any finite subset of any space is compact. Do you see why? *HINT: If $A$ is finite, write $A=\{a_1, . . . , a_n\}$; now if $\mathcal{U}=\{U_i: i\in I\}$ is an open cover of $A$, how many elements of $\mathcal{U}$ does it take to cover $\{a_1\}$? $\{a_1, a_2\}$? . . . All of $A$?*

---

Side note: in $\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[-3, 3]$ is also compact, but this is harder to show.